# Does anyone know of a dragon companion prestige class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, product-identification

I am looking for a rules supplement covering a prestige class that had a dragon companion.  The character got the dragon on an island, and bonded with it while leveling the class.  Eventually the character gained the lifespan of the dragon to which they were bonded.

I cannot remember the name of the product, but I believe it was for D&D 3.x.

Comment: Can this be narrowed even more? Are there other class features you remember? Was the product official or third party? Was the source online, magazine, hardcover, or softcover? Were there nearby illustrations?

Comment: Prestige classes don't usually have a personal story that goes with them, like you describe with the character getting the dragon on an island. Are you sure this is a prestige class, and not some fiction you read?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm trying to remember as many specifics as I can about the book it was located. I'm truly sorry for the confusion and my lack of memory.

Comment: I seem to further recalled that it was more of a mount than companion... I seem to recalled something about them being bonded in a ritual... I'm sorry for bring so vague. If I could remember more I would expound further.

Comment: Do not answer in comments.  Answer in answers.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the dragon lifespan, the only thing I can think of that resembles what you are describing (mechanic-wise) is either the Dracolyte ((Draconomicon, p. 122) or the Dragon Rider (Dragonlance Campaign Setting, p. 77).

The Dracolyte has:

> **Foster Dragon:** At 5<sup>th</sup> level, a dracolyte is entrusted with the care of a wyrmling dragon.

The Dragon Rider has:

> **Dragon Cohort:** At 1<sup>st</sup> level the dragon rider may designate a dragon that he has previously ridden as his dragon cohort.